# Why am I getting this swift error? missing argument for parameter 'price' in call

Tags: swift

Issue:  I'm trying to create a custom object with json data, however swift is giving me an error thats theres a missing parameter when im looping/adding data to the object, Yet in the model im using an optional so I'm confused where the problem lies. ultimately this data will go into a table view.

My model (using optionals):

```
class FlightDataModel {
    var airline: String?
    var price: String?

    init(airline: String?, price: String?) {
        self.airline = airline
        self.price = price
    }  
}
```

The alamofire API request..

```
 request(qpxRequest).responseJSON { (request, response, json, error) -> Void in
        if response != nil {
            //NSLog("%@", response!)
        }

        if json != nil {
            if let myJSON = json as? [String:AnyObject] {
                if let trips = myJSON["trips"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
                    if let data = trips["data"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
                        if let carriers = data["carrier"] as? [[String:String]] {

                            for (index, carrierName) in enumerate(carriers) {
```

//                                 -----PROBLEM AREA-------------

```
                             let myFlight = FlightDataModel(airline: carrierName["name"] as String)

                                self.arrayOfFlights[index] = myFlight
                                //println("\(self.arrayOfFlights[index].airline)")


                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`price` is a parameter to your `init` constructor.  An argument must be provided, even if the parameter is of an *optional* type.  If you don't have a value for it, you can give it `nil`:

```
let myFlight = FlightDataModel(airline: carrierName["name"] as String, price: nil)
```

---

If you wanted `price` to default to `nil` if that argument is not provided you do one of two things:

1. You could provide a default value for `price` in the initializer:

   ```
   init(airline: String?, price: String? = nil) {
       self.airline = airline
       self.price = price
   }
   ```
2. You could provide a second separate `init` that just takes an `airline`:

   ```
   init(airline: String?) {
       self.airline = airline
   }
   ```

Comment: so i added that and nor the error gives: fatal error: Array index out of range. on the next line of code

Comment: Technically, that is another question.  How is your array declared?  You probably just want to use `append` to add the flight to `arrayOfFlights`.

Comment: var arrayOfFlights : [FlightDataModel] = [FlightDataModel]()

Comment: `arrayOfFlights.append(myFlight)`

Comment: so do i also make airline:nil when inputting the price data? and then access data like: myFlight[0].price and myFlight[0].airline  ?

Comment: The values will be `nil` since they're optional vars if you don't initialize them to anything else.  The `init` is called when you initially create the object with `FlightDataModel(...)`.  You can later set the airline with `myFlight.airline = "United"` and price with `myFlight.price = 600`.  If you access data directly from your `arrayOfFlights` with `arrayOfFlights[0].airline` and `arrayOfFlights[0].price`.

Comment: i dont think i made the question clear,  When I make this statement -    var myFlight = FlightDataModel(airline: carrierName["name"] as String!, price:nil)  price is nil.. but when i do this - var myFlight = FlightDataModel(airline:nil, price: theprice["saleTotal"] as String!)      the airlilne is already full of data? so wont that erase it back to nil?

Comment: `FlightDataModel(airline:nil, price: theprice["saleTotal"] as String!)` creates a brand new object and sets the price.  If you want to update the price of an already created object, you would do `myFlight.price = theprice["saleTotal"] as String`.